# Getting VM guest datastore utilisation from SQL

Tags: vmware-vsphere

We run various reports directly from the vSphere 4.1 database, to get a tactical overview of things like snapshots, reservations, etc.

The problem I have at the moment is that I can't find out the guest's datastore usage.

So the VM is from VPX_VM:

```
SELECT VM.ID, ENTITY.NAME
FROM VPX_VM VM
INNER JOIN VPX_ENTITY ENTITY ON (VM.ID=ENTITY.ID)

/*
ID | NAME
41 | Guest1
/*
```

I can get the guest usage from VPX_GUEST_DISK:

```
SELECT *
FROM VPX_GUEST_DISK

/*
VM_ID | PATH | CAPACITY | FREE_SPACE
   41 | C:\  |    30 Gb |      10 Gb
   41 | D:\  |    25 Gb |      20 Gb
   41 | F:\  |   100 Gb |      15 Gb
   41 | G:\  |   100 Gb |       4 Gb
   41 | H:\  |   100 Gb |      20 Gb
   41 | I:\  |   250 Gb |      10 Gb
   41 | J:\  |    50 Gb |       9 Gb
*/
```

And I can find out which datastores are being used from VPX_DS_ASSIGNMENT:

```
SELECT VM.ID, ENTITY.NAME, ASS.DS_ID, DS.NAME
FROM
    VPX_VM VM
    INNER JOIN VPX_ENTITY ENTITY ON (VM.ID=ENTITY.ID)
    LEFT JOIN VPX_DS_ASSIGNMENT ASS ON (ASS.ENTITY_ID=VM.ID)
    LEFT JOIN VPX_DATASTORE DS ON (ASS.DS_ID=DS.ID)

/*
ID | NAME   | DS_ID | NAME
41 | Guest1 |    15 | Datastore1
41 | Guest1 |    21 | Datastore2
41 | Guest1 |    50 | Datastore3
41 | Guest1 |   380 | Datastore4
41 | Guest1 |   382 | Datastore5
*/
```

Note that there are only 5 assignments here, because the guest's F: and G: disks are on the same datastore, and it's I: and J: disks are on the same (different) datastore.

But I cannot find out is how much of each datastore is being used.  What I really need is the link that tells me which datastore each VPX_GUEST_DISK is on.

This is what I need as an end-result:

```
ID | NAME   | DS_ID | NAME       | ASSIGNED
41 | Guest1 |    15 | Datastore1 |    30 Gb
41 | Guest1 |    21 | Datastore2 |    25 Gb
41 | Guest1 |    50 | Datastore3 |    25 Gb
41 | Guest1 |   380 | Datastore4 |   100 Gb
41 | Guest1 |   382 | Datastore5 |   300 Gb
```

or even

```
ID | NAME   | DS_ID | NAME       | ASSIGNED
41 | Guest1 |    15 | Datastore1 |    30 Gb
41 | Guest1 |    21 | Datastore2 |    25 Gb
41 | Guest1 |    50 | Datastore3 |   100 Gb
41 | Guest1 |    50 | Datastore3 |   100 Gb
41 | Guest1 |   380 | Datastore4 |   100 Gb
41 | Guest1 |   382 | Datastore5 |   250 Gb
41 | Guest1 |   382 | Datastore5 |    50 Gb
```

(The sizes I've shown are in Gb for clarity, but in the database are actually in bytes)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
select 
    ds.ds_name, ds.ds_capacity_gb, ds.ds_free_gb,
    -- vm.name, 
    substring(vm.name, len(ds.storage_url) + 1, len(vm.name) - len(ds.storage_url)) file_name, 
    CONVERT(decimal(10, 0), CONVERT(decimal(15, 0), vm.file_size) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS file_size_gb,
    vm.type
from vpx_vm_fle_file_info vm, 
    (select name as ds_name, storage_url, CONVERT(decimal(10, 0), CONVERT(decimal(15, 0), CAPACITY) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS ds_capacity_gb, 
        CONVERT(decimal(10, 0), CONVERT(decimal(15, 0), FREE_SPACE) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS ds_free_gb
    from vpx_datastore) ds
where vm_id = 7000
    -- filter by datastores
    and substring(vm.name, 1, len(ds.storage_url)) = ds.storage_url
```

-- Comment this for all VM files; this filters only files over 1 GB approx.
    and file_size > 1e9